# get all parents values and index from text c#

Tags: c#, indexing, tree, binary-tree, parent-child

I have below string as input and need parent child values and the index.

> \n \n\nClassified as Internal \n\nSchedule \n\nThis is the second line for this document. \n\n1. First Point. (Index = 1) \n\n \n\na. First Sub point level 1. (Index = 1.1)  \n\n \n\nb. Second Sub point level1. (Index = 1.2) \n\n \n\n1. First Sub point Level 2 (Index = 1.2.1) \n\n \n\nA. First Sub point Level 3 (Index = 1.2.1.1) \n\ni. First Sub point Level 4 (Index = 1.2.1.1.1) \n\nii. Second Sub point Level 4 (Index = 1.2.1.1.2) \n\niii. Third Sub point Level 4 (Index = 1.2.1.1.3) \n\niv. Fourth Sub point Level 4 (Index = 1.2.1.1.4) \n\n1.  First Sub point Level 5 (Index = 1.2.1.1.4.1) \n\n2.  Second Sub point Level 5 (Index = 1.2.1.1.4.2) \n\n3.  Third Sub point Level 5 (Index = 1.2.1.1.4.3) \n\nB. Second Sub point Level 3 (Index = 1.2.1.2) \n\nC. Third Sub point Level 3 (Index = 1.2.1.3) \n\nD. Fourth Sub point Level 3 (Index = 1.2.1.4) \n\n \n\n2. Second Sub point Level 2 (Index = 1.2.2) \n\nA. First Sub point Level 3 (Index = 1.2.2.1) \n\n \n\n\n

And the format of the document is per below:
[image]

Now, i need to have result in below format:

> ==============================================================

[image]
Please note the "**(Index = 1.2.*)**" is just for representation and actual wont have it.

Comment: What have you tried? And why was that not working? SO is not a 'please write my code' community.

Comment: I am not looking for whole code but atleast any idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: You could do something with File.ReadAllLines. Iterate over those. Check the first character. Create some logic to see which depth you are in based on the first character. Use the `IndexOf` method to get to the place where your index number is

Comment: Thanks for reply but there is a challenge in retrieving the depth as the proper indexing against each point is not there. What i mean is if the Item is at "1.2" index looking at the document. But we get in string as "2.". And this can't be controlled as the user can have document in any format.

Comment: I suppose you can look at the text inside the parentheses to get your depth? (1.2) so you're at depth 1.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you but i have written note in actual post **"Please note the "(Index = 1.2.*)" is just for representation and actual wont have it."**

Comment: If the document is in any format and you can't control it, you may want to consider machine learning/image recognition. You will not be able to write code to cover all formats. Otherwise, just start writing done code. Trial and error. Try to get your specifications right. If you know your specifications, the code will be easier to write. I'm going to abandon this question for further comments. Good luck.